# How to check if an element in Pandas df row has a value with equality sign(the value after the sign changes)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-structures, data-science

I have a dataframe with conditions like this:

```
  condition1 Condition2 Condition3 Condition4
0 duck>1          goat>2     sheep=0    chicken=0
1 duck=0          chicken=0  donkey>1   zebra>0
```

And a list with a single condition to check against the df as:

```
list = ['goat','goat','duck','goat','duck']
```

From this list I have created another list which shows the number occurences of each element in list1

```
list2 = ['goat=3','duck=2']
```

For this example, I want to get back row '0' in the df since the conditions are all met(note: absence of sheep and chicken in my list is equal to sheep=0 and chicken=0).

The number of categories in conditions(in this case animals) are so many to define them beforehand.

How would I check and get back the rows where the conditions are met?

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the program to return the row in which all the conditions have been met, is that right?

Comment: Exactly @RhysFlook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are other ways to get `list2`, which would have been better suited to this problem. This solution is purely based on your variables:

**1. Straightforward (Bruteforce) method:**

```
list2 = ['goat=3','duck=2']
dict2 = dict(item.split('=') for item in list2)
comparison_func = {'>': lambda x,y: x > y, 
                   '<': lambda x,y: x < y, 
                   '=': lambda x,y: x == y}

valid_rows = []
for row_ix, row_contents in df.iterrows():
    conditions_met = True
    for condition in row_contents:
        for operator in comparison_func:
            if operator in condition:
                animal, value = condition.split(operator)
                break

        is_true = comparison_func[operator]
        if not is_true(int(dict2.get(animal,0)), int(value)):
            conditions_met = False
            break
    if conditions_met:
        valid_rows.append(row_ix)
print(valid_rows)
```

Output:

```
[0]
```

Later you can do:

```
>>> df['conditions_met'] = df.index.isin(valid_rows)
>>> df
  condition1 Condition2 Condition3 Condition4  conditions_met
0     duck>1     goat>2    sheep=0  chicken=0            True
1     duck=0  chicken=0   donkey>1    zebra>0           False
```

**2. Smart Method:**

```
>>> list2 = ['goat=3','duck=2']
>>> dict2 = dict(item.split('=') for item in list2)
>>> globals().update(dict2)

>>> def is_true(x):
...     if '>' in x:
...         animal, value = x.split('>')
...         return int(globals().get(animal, 0)) > int(value)
...     elif '<' in x:
...         animal, value = x.split('<')
...         return int(globals().get(animal, 0)) < int(value)
...     else:
...         animal, value = x.split('=')
...         return int(globals().get(animal, 0)) == int(value)

>>> df.applymap(is_true)
   condition1  Condition2  Condition3  Condition4
0        True        True        True        True
1       False        True       False       False

>>> df[df.applymap(is_true).all(1)].index
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')

>>> df['conditions_met'] = df.applymap(is_true).all(1)

>>> df
  condition1 Condition2 Condition3 Condition4  conditions_met
0     duck>1     goat>2    sheep=0  chicken=0            True
1     duck=0  chicken=0   donkey>1    zebra>0           False
```

**EXPLANATION for method 1**:

```
# make a dict out of list2, there are other ways  
# to get to the next step directly from list1
dict2 = dict(item.split('=') for item in list2)

# make a mapping of checker functions wrt operators
comparison_func = {'>': lambda x,y: x > y, 
                   '<': lambda x,y: x < y, 
                   '=': lambda x,y: x == y}

# create an empty list to keep provision for the case
# when conditions are matched in multiple rows
valid_rows = []

# Iterate over the dataframe
for row_ix, row_contents in df.iterrows():

    # set a flag for each row
    conditions_met = True

    # iterate through each column in the row
    for condition in row_contents:

        # check which operator is in the current column
        for operator in comparison_func:

            # if operator found, split by it, store the (animal, value) and break
            if operator in condition:
                animal, value = condition.split(operator)
                break
        # get the comparison function for the operator, name the function is_true
        is_true = comparison_func[operator]

        # check if the function evaluates to true with given values
        # dict2.get(animal,0) will give the value for that animal from dict2
        # if the animal is not in dict2 it will return default value 0
        if not is_true(int(dict2.get(animal,0)), int(value)):
            # if condition did not meet, set conditions_met False, break
            conditions_met = False
            break

    # outside the loop, if the conditions_met stays True throughout the previous loop
    # append the row index to the valid_rows
    if conditions_met:
        valid_rows.append(row_ix)

print(valid_rows)
```

**Explanation for method 2**:

[`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) is a python builtin function that gives access to the global variables in the namespace, via a dictionary. Here I update `global` namespace with `dict2`, i.e., now both `goat` and `duck` exist as global variables, and can be accessed from inside other functions for comparison.

[`df.applymap(func)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) applies a function to each element of a dataframe.

[`df.all(axis)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) checks if all values evaluate to `True` across given `axis`.

And that's it.

Answer (score 1):

So I can't think of a simple solution for this, but I would start by making that second list into a dictionary that reads like this.

```
dict1 = {'goat': 3, 'duck':2}
```

Let's just imagine you have two conditions for now, e.g. 'duck>0' and 'goat>2'.

I would make a function to turn the conditionals in the dataframe to actual conditionals.

```
def animal_counter(condition1, condition2):
    # I will just show one example here but you would have to make more conditionals
    all_conditions_met = False
    for condition in (condition1, condition2):
        if '>' in condition:
            # by splitting the condition by the conditional symbol
            # we get two useful parts, the animal name and the number
            # which we can compare against the dictionary to get a boolean result
            animal_num = condition.split('>')

        try:
            if dict1[animal_num[0]] > int(animal_num[1]):
                all_conditions_met = True
            else:
                # By putting this return statement here we end the function if one
                # condition returns as False
                all_conditions_met = False
                return all_conditions_met

        except Keyerror:
            if int(animal_num[1]) > 0:
                all_conditions_met = False
                return all_conditions_met
            else:
                all_conditions_met = True

    return all_conditions_met
```

Then I would iterate through the dataframe and take each condition as a string.

```
true_rows = []
for row in df.iterrows():
    # row[0] would return the index, row[1] gets the rest of the row
    condition1 = row[1]['condition1']
    condition2 = row[1]['condition2']

    # pass the strings into the animal_counter function
    true_or_false = animal_counter(condition1, condition2)

    if true_or_false:
        true_rows.append(row[0])
```

This should return a list of the indexes of all rows where the conditions are met.

You just need to expand on it a little to make it work for all possible conditionals and more columns.

Answer (score 1):

use collections.Counter to get the count of items in list, then apply a function which check for your condition to each row using [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

let your Dataframe and list be

```
>>df
  condition1.   condition2  condition3  condition4
0     duck>1        goat>2     sheep=0   chicken=0
1     duck=0     chicken=0    donkey>1     zebra>0
2     duck=4     chicken=0    donkey>1     zebra>0

>>lst
['goat','goat','duck','goat','duck']
```

function to pass to apply

```
from collections import Counter
from collections import Counter
def bar(op,ctr,item):
    item = item.split(op)
    val = ctr.get(item[0])
    if item:
        if val:
            if op == '=':
                if int(val) < int(item[1]):
                    return False
            elif op == '>':
                if int(val) <= int(item[1]):
                    return False
        else:
            if int(item[1]) !=0:
                return False
    return True

def foo(row,lst):
    ctr = dict(Counter(lst))
    for item in list(row):
        if '=' in item:
            if not bar('=',ctr,item):
                return False  
                    
        elif '>' in item:
            if not bar('>',ctr,item):
                return False   
    return True
```

```
df1['select'] = df.apply(lambda x: foo(x,lst),axis=1)
>>> print(df1[df1.select])
  condition1 condition2 condition3 condition4   select
0     duck>1     goat>2    sheep=0  chicken=0     True
```

**EDIT**:corrected code

Comment: For the 2nd row in the df, its conditions are not met by the list. It should return False @Shijith